# Set user permissions for specific views in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I am using Django to make a website with a bunch of different pages.  I only have views, I have not defined any models in my project.  I want certain users to have restricted access (they can only see some of the views I've created).  I've set up some users in the Django admin site and added login functionality to my website using the Python `@login_required` decorator.

I'm a little lost on how to set viewing permissions for each user though.  I've looked at the `@permission_required` decorator but it seems to only pertain to models and not views.  How do you set page viewing permissions in Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use user_passes_test decorator for views. Django documentation has a nice example of it's usage
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

Edited: actually you can use permission_required decorator for views also
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required

Comment: The `user_passes_test` decorator looks perfect.  Do you know if it's possible to use it on groups as well as individual users?

Comment: @kdubs yes, sure you can. There is a good example here 
https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/restricting-access-by-group-in-django/

I've used it in one of my project and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Permissions are linked to models. If your authorization logic is linked to the view and not to a model, consider creating a group and using the [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator. For example, lets say you have a report that only supervisors can see: create a group named Supervisors and test for membership:

```
def must_be_supervisor(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='Supervisors').count()

@user_passes_test(must_be_supervisor)
def quarter_report(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `django-braces`. It's a superb app for exactly this purpose;
https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

It provides a mixin for almost every eventuality for use in views & forms which allow you to perform checks to restrict access how you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use permission_required in urls to lock

example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf

Comment: Links to external sources are ok, but they can break in the future, then your answer would be useless. It would help, if you simply copied the relevant part(maybe a code snippet with sample usage) in your answer together with the link.